# How to update the first row of a table in dolphindb?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

Does anyone know how to write the where conditions for the first row for dolphindb?

```sql
update table set x=100 where ?
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the dolphindb function rowNo:

```
update t set x=100 where rowNo(x)=0
```